# How to code on multiple devices with Git versioning?

Tags: git, device

I have a desktop and a laptop device I am coding on. I would like both environments to stay synched without pushing every unfinished work to the server. That would be annoying for other developers of that project and unnecessary bloats the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having similar issue for some period of time until I figured out I could store my project folder in a dropbox folder. So every time I change something in the project it is automatically synced with all my devices through dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

if you work on topic branches, you could possibly push the changes without affecting others. If you are having multiple people work on one topic branch, have each developer branch from that topic branch into their own areas. This will allow proper merging whenever someone else merges with the topic branch and easy merging back into the master branch once the topic branch is finished.

Branching is the proper `git` answer. Its cheap, quick, and uses only `git` functionality without needing to go to a 3rd party tool (any cloud storage)...

Answer (score 1):

If you've got your filesystems LAN-mounted via NFS/homegroup/samba/whatnot just push to your personal repo pathnames directly, no url or remote name required.

If that's inconvenient you could also do quickie temporary pushes by opening a [git-daemon](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) and pushing to git://its-lan-ip/